# How do I make each of the list items in an array clickable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

I have a list of different cities that I have to sort by location closest to me.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t24g3umj/

```
var jsonString ='{"City A":{"Position":{"Longitude":9.96233,"Latitude":49.80404}},"City B":{"Position":{"Longitude":6.11499,"Latitude":50.76891}},"City C":{"Position":{"Longitude":6.80592,"Latitude":51.53548}},"City D":{"Position":{"Longitude":9.50523,"Latitude":51.31991}},"City E":{"Position":{"Longitude":9.66089,"Latitude":48.70158}},"City F":{"Position":{"Longitude":9.93368,"Latitude":53.55608}},"City G":{"Position":{"Longitude":11.56122,"Latitude":48.14496}},"City H":{"Position":{"Longitude":13.34253,"Latitude":52.5319}},"City I":{"Position":{"Longitude":6.11327,"Latitude":50.77715}},"City J":{"Position":{"Longitude":13.36671,"Latitude":52.54344}}}';

var myData = JSON.parse(jsonString);

$(document).ready(function () {

var distanceObj = [],
    i = 0;
$.each(myData, function (a, b) {
    distanceObj[i] = {
        distance: hesapla(9.9608999, 49.7222842, b.Position.Longitude, b.Position.Latitude),
        location: a
    };
    ++i;
});

distanceObj.sort(function (a, b) {
    return parseInt(a.distance) - parseInt(b.distance)
});

$.each(distanceObj, function (a, b) {
    $('#groups').append('<li>' + b.location + ': ' + b.distance + 'm</li>');
});

console.log(distanceObj);

function hesapla(meineLongitude, meineLatitude, long1, lat1) {
    erdRadius = 6371;

    meineLongitude = meineLongitude * (Math.PI / 180);
    meineLatitude = meineLatitude * (Math.PI / 180);
    long1 = long1 * (Math.PI / 180);
    lat1 = lat1 * (Math.PI / 180);

    x0 = meineLongitude * erdRadius * Math.cos(meineLatitude);
    y0 = meineLatitude * erdRadius;

    x1 = long1 * erdRadius * Math.cos(lat1);
    y1 = lat1 * erdRadius;

    dx = x0 - x1;
    dy = y0 - y1;

    d = Math.sqrt((dx * dx) + (dy * dy));


    return Math.round(d * 1000);
};
});
```

I am wondering, how to make each of the li elements clickable?

Also, a secondary question is how to filter a special city to the top of the list regardless of distance?

Thanks in advance to the wonderful community at stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can also use delegated event binding on the handler using [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/), given that you are adding li dynamically:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#groups').on('click', 'li', function() {
       // handler here
    }
```

2. You can use jQuery [`.prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) to add an li to the top of the list, instead of `append()` which adds it to the bottom

```
$('#groups').prepend('<li>I am special ...</li>');
```

Comment: I'm still not 100% sure how to use the first part of the code. How do I make each li link to a different page?

Comment: When you create the Li elements, embed any data you will need to construct the link in data- attributes, which you can then use in the handler.

Answer (score 0):

Is that You Want?

```
$.each(distanceObj, function(a, b) {
    $('#groups').append('<li><a href="#">' + b.location + ': ' + b.distance + 'm </a></li>');
});
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of that but that would make all of the li elements lead to the same link. I should have been more specific, because I am trying to make each li element link to a different page.

Answer (score 0):

To make the elements clickable, you need to use `"<a>"` tag, within each li. Below is the modified code.

```
$.each(distanceObj, function(a, b) {
    $('#groups').append('<li><a href="#">' + b.location + ': ' + b.distance + 'm </a></li>');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t24g3umj/1/

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of that but that would make all of the li elements lead to the same link. I should have been more specific, because I am trying to make each li element link to a different page.